# How to partition a table copied from another schema?

Tags: oracle, copy, schema, partition

I want to copy a table from one schema into another. Then I want to partition the table.  How do I partition a table that I've copied from another schema?

From what I understand about partitioning, this should work, but I keep getting the missing left parenthesis error - which means probably that the syntax is incorrect?

```
DROP TABLE SS_CUSTOMER;
CREATE TABLE SS_Customer AS SELECT * FROM WL.CUSTOMER
 PARTITION BY HASH(CUST_ID),
   PARTITIONS 4 
   STORE IN (USERS, USERS, CUSTOMER, CUSTOMER);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your only option is to do this in multiple steps.  First, create the partitioned table.  Then, run an `INSERT` statement that selects data from the source table.  I don't believe it is possible to do a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` that creates a partitioned table.

As an aside, I can't believe that your partition names are correct.  If you're going to name your hash partitions, you'd have to use different names-- creating two partitions named `USERS` and two named `CUSTOMER` is not going to work.

Comment: I created the partition and inserted the data.  I did this by removing the constraints, which means I will have to add them back in, but it worked, Thank you.